Can I change the order of this repeated limit?
Consider the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P},\theta_{n}),{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. $f_n:\Omega\to\mathbb{R_{\leq0}}\cup\{-\infty\}$. Suppose $f_n$ is subadditive, that is,
$$f_{n+m}(\omega)\leq f_n(\omega)+f_m(\theta_{n}\omega),~~m,n\geq0,\omega\in\Omega.$$
Assume $f_n^{+}\in L^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$.
For any $N>0$, define $f_n^{N}(\omega)=\max\{f_n(\omega),-Nn\}$. Then $f_n^{N}(\omega)\in[-N,0]$ and subadditive, it follows Kingman subadditive theorem that $$\exists f^{N}\in L^{1}, s.t.~ f_{n}^N(\omega)\to f^{N}(\omega),n\to\infty~~a.e.~and~L^{1}.$$
One the other hand, $f_n^N(\omega)\geq f_{n+1}^N(\omega)$, thus $f^{N}(\omega)\geq f^{N+1}(\omega)$. Hence there exists $f^{\infty}(\omega)$ (may be $-\infty$) such that $f^N(\omega)\to f^{\infty}(\omega),N\to\infty.$
Now we have $$\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\frac{f_n^N(\omega)}{n}=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\displaystyle\frac{f^N(\omega)}{n}=f^{\infty}(\omega)~~a.e.$$
My question is that can we conclude that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\displaystyle\frac{f_n^N(\omega)}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\frac{f_n(\omega)}{n}=f^{\infty}(\omega)~~a.e.$$
